# drop into UIImage failed (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop

Here i am trying to drag image and drop it into UIImage in my app but when i try to drag any picture to my app in iPad simulator, the `+` sign doesn't appear and the drop action doesn't happen.

Find below my code

```
import UIKit

class EmojiArtViewController: UIViewController , UIDropInteractionDelegate{


    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!{
        didSet{
            backgroundImage.addInteraction(UIDropInteraction(delegate: self))
        }
    }

// MARK:- drop functions:

    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, canHandle session: UIDropSession) -> Bool {
        return session.canLoadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self)
    }

    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, sessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession) -> UIDropProposal {
        return UIDropProposal(operation: .copy)
    }

    func dropInteraction(_ interaction: UIDropInteraction, performDrop session: UIDropSession) {

        session.loadObjects(ofClass: UIImage.self) { images in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let image = images.first as? UIImage {
                    self.backgroundImage.image = image
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/may0l.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set

```
backgroundImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```